# Sort list of items and add custom titles on top of filtered items in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to sort a list of items and to add a custom title/header on top of some items from the list like in the photo attached below:
[image]

What I try to achieve is that if the first element from the list have the property "isHooked = true" then I want to add on top of first row a header called "Current Trailer" and on top of second row I want to add a header called "Past Trailers" which will include the other items from the list.

Can you help me to understand what I'm doing wrong in my code ?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Trailer {
  Trailer({this.trailerPlate, this.isHookup, this.time});

  String? trailerPlate = "";
  bool? isHookup = false;
  String? time = "";
}

List<Trailer> trailersHistory = [
  Trailer(trailerPlate: "Trailer4", isHookup: true, time: "16:00"),
  Trailer(trailerPlate: "Trailer3", isHookup: false, time: "15:00"),
  Trailer(trailerPlate: "Trailer2", isHookup: false, time: "14:00"),
  Trailer(trailerPlate: "Trailer1", isHookup: false, time: "13:00"),
];

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget customCard({required Widget widget, required Color cardColor}) {
    return Card(
      color: cardColor,
      child: Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0), child: widget),
    );
  }

  Widget displayTrailersHistoryTable() {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        (trailersHistory.first.isHookup ?? false) == true
            ? const Text("Current Trailer",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green))
            : const Text("Past Trailers", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red)),
        Expanded(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(
                parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              ),
              itemCount: trailersHistory.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                Trailer currentTrailer = trailersHistory[index];
                return customCard(
                    widget: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          Text(currentTrailer.trailerPlate ?? ""),
                          (currentTrailer.isHookup ?? false)
                              ? const Icon(
                                  Icons.add_circle,
                                  color: Colors.green,
                                  size: 30.0,
                                )
                              : const Icon(
                                  Icons.remove_circle,
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                  size: 30.0,
                                ),
                          Text("@ ${currentTrailer.time}")
                        ]),
                    cardColor: Colors.grey);
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
      child: displayTrailersHistoryTable(),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is also a link to my small demo:
[Dart Pad Link for Demo](https://dartpad.dev/?id=c8119e79b91cc08dc8affb0d3a9cf931)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seem like you want "Past Trailers" to be between the items made by the itemBuilder. Here is a possible solution.

At the start of the function displayTrailersHistoryTable put:`bool hasCurrentTrailer = (trailersHistory.first.isHookup ?? false);`. Then make itemCount into: `itemCount: hasCurrentTrailer ? trailersHistory.length+1 : trailersHistory.length,`. At the start of the item builder put: `int newIndex = index;`. Then next line is: `if(hasCurrentTrailer) { if(index == 1) return const Text("Past Trailers", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red)); if(index > 1) newIndex--; }`. Now you just have to get the trailer from trailer history using newIndex instead of index. With these changes you will get "Past Trailers" in between the first and second item in the case that the first item isHookup equals true.

--- Update, steps to make top text scrollable ---

Remove the first child from the columns children as we move it to the itemBuilder. Set itemCount to `itemCount: hasCurrentTrailer ? trailersHistory.length+2 : trailersHistory.length+1,`.

The first line in itemBuilder will be: `if(index == 0) return hasCurrentTrailer ? const Text("Current Trailer", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green)) : const Text("Past Trailers", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red));`.

Update the line before currentTrailer to: `if(hasCurrentTrailer) { if(index == 2) return const Text("Past Trailers", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red)); if(index > 2) newIndex--; }`.

Finally change `trailersHistory[newIndex]` to `trailersHistory[newIndex-1]`.

Now the top text is the first item in the list and is now scrollable.

Comment: Thank you. I will post the full working code if someone need it in the future. Also the `Gist` link was updated on GitHub.

Comment: I should also mention that when saying that we are putting the text "Past Trailers" between the first two items, that the implementation that I gave is making the text "Past Trailers" the second item in the list and that the text could be scrolled off the list, that may not be what you wanted. If you want the top text above the first item to also be scrollable, then you could make further edits and add the first text into the item builder. If you want both fixed in place you could try in the case you have a current trailer, split the list into two list. List1 with one item. List2 with rest.

Comment: I will like the top text above the first item to also be scrollable like the "Past Trailers". I didn't managed to make the code work. If you have any idea how this can be implemented and if you have some time, then I will really apreciate it ! The link for demo have already the latest modifications suggested by you. Thanks !

Comment: Added an update to my answer.

Comment: Thanks again @AtMaintx ! Gist project from GitHub was updated for who else will need something like this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @AtMaintx I managed to implement the solution.
Here is the full code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47),
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Trailer {
  Trailer({this.trailerPlate, this.isHookup, this.time});

  String? trailerPlate = "";
  bool? isHookup = false;
  String? time = "";
}

List<Trailer> trailersHistory = [
  Trailer(trailerPlate: "Trailer4", isHookup: true, time: "16:00"),
  Trailer(trailerPlate: "Trailer3", isHookup: false, time: "15:00"),
  Trailer(trailerPlate: "Trailer2", isHookup: false, time: "14:00"),
  Trailer(trailerPlate: "Trailer1", isHookup: false, time: "13:00"),
];

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget customCard({required Widget widget, required Color cardColor}) {
    return Card(
      color: cardColor,
      child: Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0), child: widget),
    );
  }

  Widget displayTrailersHistoryTable() {
    bool hookedCurrentTrailer = (trailersHistory.first.isHookup ?? false);
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(
          parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        ),
        itemCount: hookedCurrentTrailer
            ? trailersHistory.length + 2
            : trailersHistory.length + 1,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          int newIndex = index;
          if (index == 0) {
            return hookedCurrentTrailer
                ? const Text("Current Trailer",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green))
                : const Text("Past Trailers",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red));
          }
          if (hookedCurrentTrailer) {
            if (index == 2) {
              return const Text("Past Trailers",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red));
            }
            if (index > 2) {
              newIndex--;
            }
          }
          Trailer currentTrailer = trailersHistory[newIndex - 1];
          return Column(
            children: [
              customCard(
                  widget: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Text(currentTrailer.trailerPlate ?? ""),
                        (currentTrailer.isHookup ?? false)
                            ? const Icon(
                                Icons.add_circle,
                                color: Colors.green,
                                size: 30.0,
                              )
                            : const Icon(
                                Icons.remove_circle,
                                color: Colors.red,
                                size: 30.0,
                              ),
                        Text("@ ${currentTrailer.time}")
                      ]),
                  cardColor: Colors.grey),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
      child: displayTrailersHistoryTable(),
    );
  }
}
```